# Add actions using Rails admin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

Suppose I want to add two actions(active and pause) with the show edit delete and show_in_app actions.
So how can i accomplish this? I went through https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Actions but i am not able to get the right way..

this is my rails_admin.rb

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|    

config.actions do
  dashboard                     # mandatory
  index                         # mandatory
  new
  export
  bulk_delete
  show
  edit
  delete
  show_in_app


 end
end
```

ANY HELP?????

Answer (score 0):

Custom actions are powerful but a bit tricky.  Here is what I did:

rails_admin.rb

```
require Rails.root.join('lib', 'rails_admin', 'custom_actions.rb')
```

custom_actions.rb

```
module RailsAdmin
  module Config
    module Actions
      class Foo
        RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.register(self)
        register_instance_option :visible? do
          # which model
        end
        register_instance_option :member do
         true
        end
        register_instance_option :link_icon do
         'fa fa-star'
        end
        register_instance_option :controller do
          Proc.new do
            # put your code here
            flash[:notice] = "your message here"
            redirect_to show_path
          end
        end
      end
```

en.yml

```
en:
  admin:
    actions:
      foo:
        menu: 'foo menu'
        title: 'foo title'
        breadcrumb: 'foo breadcrumb'
```

I wrote a blog post on it http://dmitrypol.github.io/2015/09/10/rails_admin.html